# Once the CSV file is read in page load event after postback, file length is becoming 0 in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have file upload which allows csv files, in page load for some validation i have read the inputstream of csv file. it is sucessfully read in page_load event. whereas in some button click event if i try to read the same csv file then the content length of the same csv file is showing 0.. please help.

Comment: Do you have some code samples of your `Page_Load` event and your button click event? Does this happen when pressing the button after the page has posted back once already, or are you posting back via the button straight after selecting a file to upload?

Comment: I wrote a HttpModule, in which page load event fires in the httpmodule on every page load in application. Now in pageload event of httpmodule i am able to read the uploaded csv file after postback. where as after  going to the actual page , i cant able to read the same csv file. its length is showing 0.